# Como llamar a otro método del mismo controlador en Laravel para devolver una vista condicionada

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en la creación de un elemento en varias fases en una aplicación Laravel.

Primero se registran unos datos básicos y seguidamente varios detalles. Esto lo divido en dos formularios para llegar al formulario 2 primero se deben registrar correctamente los datos introducidos en el formulario 1. Entonces en el controlador tengo 4 métodos:

```
// Devuelve la vista del primer formulario
create() {...}

// Devuelve la vista del segundo formulario
createDetails(int id) {...}

// Guarda los datos del primer formulario
store(Request $request) {...}

// Guarda los datos del segundo formulario
storeDetails(Request $request) {...}
```

La secuencia es:

Se llama a `create()` para abrir el primer formulario, se rellena y se envía. Los datos llegan a `store()`, si todo está correcto, al final de este método se hace una llamada a `createDetails($id)` para devolver el segundo formulario, **¿cómo se debe hacer esta llamada?**

Answer (score -1):

Para llamar a este método que devolverá la vista del segundo formulario, hay dos opciones:

```
return $this->createDetails($id);
```

o bien:

```
return redirect()->action(
    'MiControlador@createDetails', ['id' => $id]
);
```

La [doc de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-controller-actions), siempre algo vaga, indica el uso de la segunda opción para la llamada a acciones (métodos) de un controlador, esto es lo que haremos para llamar a un método de otro controlador, pero en este caso, como estamos llamando a un método del mismo controlador, la primera opción es más sencilla, eficiente y fácil de entender, aun sin nociones de *Laravel*, y realmente, sin usar redirecciones, lo que haría necesario también tener que crear la ruta para que la llamada a este método funcione.